# Unable to convert ggplot2 using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

[image]I have a ggplot2 chart with the following code

```
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]a <-filter(match,team==theTeam)
   # Group batsman with non strikers and compute partnerships
   df <- data.frame(summarise(group_by(a,batsman,nonStriker),sum(runs)))
   names(df) <- c("batsman","nonStriker","runs")

if(plot==TRUE){
    plot.title <- paste(theTeam,"Batting partnership in match (vs.",opposition,")")
    ggplot(data=df,aes(x=batsman,y=runs,fill=nonStriker))+
        geom_bar(data=df,stat="identity") +
        xlab("Batmen") + ylab("Runs Scored") +
        ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(plot.title),
                                atop(italic("Data source:http://cricsheet.org/"),"")))) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

which produces the chart as below.

But when I try to create an interactive chart with

```
g<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=batsman,y=runs,fill=nonStriker))+
        geom_bar(data=df,stat="identity") +
        xlab("Batmen") + ylab("Runs Scored") +
        ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(plot.title),
                                atop(italic("Data source:http://cricsheet.org/"),"")))) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
ggplotly(g)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In if (robust_nchar(plot$labels$title) > 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there anything specific that needs to be done before converting ggplot -> ggplotly?

Thanks

### Test data

batsman nonStriker      runs
JA Morkel       Joginder Sharma 21
JA Morkel       MS Dhoni        3
JA Morkel       MS Gony 5
Joginder Sharma JA Morkel       16

```
MS Dhoni        JA Morkel       1
MS Dhoni        SK Raina        22
MS Gony JA Morkel       15
PA Patel        SP Fleming      4
S Anirudha      SP Fleming      1
S Badrinath     SK Raina        0
SK Raina        MS Dhoni        16
SK Raina        S Badrinath     9
SK Raina        SP Fleming      7
SP Fleming      S Anirudha      5
SP Fleming      SK Raina        9
```

Comment: Added test data.

Comment: This seems to work. Need to get sub-heading also.  g=    ggplot(data=df,aes(x=batsman,y=runs,fill=nonStriker))+
        geom_bar(data=df,stat="identity") +
        xlab("Batmen") + ylab("Runs Scored") +
        ggtitle(plot.title) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
ggplotly(g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a [long pending open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/799) in `plotly` where the subtitles are lost from ggplot -> plotly. The fix for now is to add title and subtitle in plotly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=batsman,y=runs,fill=nonStriker))+
  geom_bar(data=df,stat="identity") +
  xlab("Batmen") + ylab("Runs Scored") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) -> g

ggplotly(g) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = paste0(plot.title, '\n<sup>Data source:http://cricsheet.org/</sup>')))
```

Comment: Yes. Got it work based on https://datascott.com/blog/subtitles-with-ggplotly/ which that you need to add HTML tags to get subtitle